# Correctness of definition of cartesian product of n sets

Tags: products

In a script I found a recursive defintion for the cartesian product of n sets:

With $P_n = \{i ∈ N_+ ∣ i ≤ n\}$

the cartesian product of sets $M_i$ with $i \in P_n$ is defined as follows:

$\times_{i\in P_1} M_i = M_1$

$\times_{i\in P_{n+1}} M_i = (\times_{i\in P_n} M_i) \times M_{n+1}$

Note: It should be a large "cross" for the cartesian product, but \bigtimes does not work in this environment.

Is this definition correct? I don't understand the subscript $i\in P_{n+1}$. For $n=4$ you could chose any $1\leq i\leq 4$, but how does the definition work out if I can arbitrarily chose this value?

Comment: It is not an arbitrary $ i\in P_{n+1}$. It kinda limit. for instance when we say  $\cup _{i\in P_{n+1}}A_i$ it means $A_1\cup A_2 \cup \cdots \cup A_{n+1}$

Comment: @Gune Unions are defined in terms of the Axiom of Union, rather than an inductive process. So no, it's not a good analogy.

Comment: @DonThousand I just wanted to emphasize we don't do it for arbitrary  $i$. Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the definition is correct.

$\times_{i\in P_1} M_i = M_1$

$\times_{i\in P_{n+1}} M_i = (\times_{i\in P_n} M_i) \times M_{n+1}$

then for your case when $n=4$ we have,

$ \begin{split}\times_{i\in P_{5+1}} M_i &= (\times_{i\in P_5} M_i) \times M_{6}\\
&=(\times_{i\in P_4} M_i)\times M_{5} \times M_{6}\\
&.\\&.\\&=(\times_{i\in P_1} M_i)\times M_{2}\times M_{3}\times M_{4} \times M_{5}\times M_{6}\\
&=M_{1}\times M_{2}\times M_{3}\times M_{4} \times M_{5}\times M_{6}\end{split}$